# How to map Cassandra map-tuple to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, nosql, full-text-search, elassandra

can someone guide me how to map the below cassandra datatype to elastic search.

```
movies map<text, frozen<tuple<text, text, bigint, double, text>>>
```

Appreciate your time, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Elassandra v6.2.3.5, tuple is not supported, nor object inside map.

It is planned for a future release.